# I can't remember the email or password i used for Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

I broke my phone and I never backed it up so I lost everything. Including Pokemon Go. It would've saved my account though, right? I tried to sign in using my username and password but my password won't work! I USE THE EXACT SAME PASSWORD FOR LITERALLY EVERYTHING I HAVE!!! Why would I use something different this one time??? I asked my friends if my username was right or wrong and they all sent me a screenshot of my profile that I sent them and the username was right. I have so many emails that I cant remember which one I used. Any advice on what I should do?

Comment: It's not wise to openly tell people on the internet you use the same password for everything.

Answer (score 2):

Your best plan of action is to throw your email addresses into the [username recovery page](https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/forgot-username) until you get a hit. This will identify which address your account is attached to, which, along with your username, will let you fill in the [password recovery form](https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/forgot-password).

After that, you should do something to consolidate all those email accounts and diversify your password situation, because... Damn, dude. This is some 101-level shit.